# Как отобразить что юзер не зарегистрирован в бд?

Tags: python, flask

я не могу понять почему не работает `else` который сообщает юзеру что его нет в базе данных и отправляет его на страницу `test.html` (для уверенности)

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET','POST'])

def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

        if user.check_password(form.password.data) and user is not None:

            login_user(user)
            flash('Logged in successfully!')

            next = request.args.get('next')

            if next == None or not next[0]=='/':
                next = url_for('welcome_user')

            return redirect(next)

        else:
            flash('You are not in database')
            return render_template('test.html')
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Логин работает а если неверные данные - нет (на `test.html` не переносит)

По (моей) логике если юзер `not None` - он нормально логинится, если же он как раз `None` - должен перелетать через `else` в `test.html`

В чем проблема?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы проверили, вообще попадает шаг в блок else? else: flash('You are not in database') print('Нет пользователя, открыта страница test.html') return render_template('test.html')

Comment: Спасибо, я изучаю фласк только неделю так что еще не понял как отслеживать print сообщения, например. В Jypiter понятно, а как во Flask? Или сообщение будет отображаться в командной строке?

Comment: Будет отображаться в консоли, Вы же запускаете в режиме отладка? Консоль открывается? пишет, что сервер запущен откройте такой то АЙ ПИ?